# How do I get all the checked checkboxes on multiple pages of a jQuery datatable

Tags: php, jquery, datatables

I have a jQuery datatable that has up to 1000 entries. I am displaying 5 of these entries per page but of course one could search and easily get to the record one is looking for or one could use the next button to goto the next page.

I have checkboxes attached to each of the rows in the datatable. My problem is that when I check some rows in one page and then move to another page and check other rows and then submit the form to some PHP handler, it only sends the checked rows in the last page. It does not send the ones I checked in the previous pages. How do I get these rows?

Comment: You have to share your code

Comment: What do you mean by "page". A section of a single HTML page/window? or different HTML pages?

Comment: JQuery datatables has its own pagination. That is what I mean by page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way would be to hold the "marked for deletion" attribute with the records: each time a pagination request gets fired, all "marked" rows are updated in the database according to the state of the checkbox.

Hiting the "delete all marked rows" - button then would not delete those checked records but those within the database which have the according attribute set (i.e. "marked for deletion = true")

this woul also account the fact that probably multiple user might do the same or working "against each other".